# Run a JavaScript Script in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am developing a web app in R/Shiny, and need to use a JavaScript Script (the previous version of the app was written solely in JS). I included the script like it said to in the Shiny tutorials, and can run the script from the web console. How do I run it in the program itself?

The name of the script is `runAllHooks([string])`

I have, in ui.R:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
tags$head(
    tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "ppp.css"), 
    tags$script(src="productPage.js")
),
mainPage(
...
   tags$button(type="button", onclick="runAllHooks(Query)", "RELOAD")
... 
))
```

in global.R:

```
Query <- #SomeInitialQuery
```

in server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
    Query <<- #SomeQueryAgain
})
```

This code doesn't work; it says Query is undefined. How do I do this? 
Thanks!

UPDATE:

I realized I wasn't using a reactive function, which was a problem.

The basically, instead of having Query in global, I now have:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
     output$Query <- #someQuery
}
```

The rest is still essentially the same. 
I guess my question morphs to how do I reference an R variable while trying to run a JS script?

Comment: Few things. First...server needs to have the session argument if you are planning on making GET POST requests which Im assuming is whats in that JS. Without knowing what "runAllHooks" does...it's impossible to anser suffice to say you should be registering input bindings for external code and not using "onClick" as an attribute in any shiny app